# Removing storefront-sorting div from the before section of Shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have already found out that I can remove sorting drop down menu and pagination from the shop page using:

```
function delay_remove() {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' , 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' , 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop','storefront_woocommerce_pagination',30);
}
```

The problem is that I still have an empty div there:

```
<div class="storefront-sorting"></div>
```

I could use style to hide the div but that would defeat the purpose of using remove_action. Is there any remove_action that I can use to remove that div as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storefront theme has its own file where you can find all hooks and filters its adding for woocommerce.

you can find it at this path:  **storefront/inc/woocommerce/storefront-woocommerce-template-hooks.php**

To remove  storefront-sorting div, you can add the following in your child theme's functions.php:

```
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop','storefront_sorting_wrapper',9 ); //.storefront-sorting opening after products loop
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop','storefront_sorting_wrapper_close',31 ); //.storefront-sorting closing after products loop
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop','storefront_sorting_wrapper',9 );//.storefront-sorting opening before products loop
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop','storefront_sorting_wrapper_close',31 ); //.storefront-sorting closing before products loop
```